# Get value from dataframe based on column Name and row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {
    'weekbegin': ['4/11/2019', '11/11/2019'],
    '1': [3, 4],
    '2': [31, 4],
    '12': [3, 4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and following inputs:

```
value = 4
week = '4/11/2019'
```

My question:

I am looking for a cell that has column_named == value and row == '4/11/2019'.

For the given example, the expected answer is **31**

## What I have tried so far:

To get the column name:

```
df.loc[(df['weekbegin'] == week) & (df[str(value)])]
```

but it returns the row.

```
    weekbegin   1   2   12
0   4/11/2019   3   31  3
```

Comment: I don't understand how you got *31*. Shouldn't the value be 2?

Comment: No, 2 is a column name
@Vishnudev -- Answer provided by jezrael might clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need for second argumement in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) column name, so use:

```
out = df.loc[(df['weekbegin'] == week), str(value)]
```

If possible `value` not matching use:

```
out = df.loc[(df['weekbegin'] == week), df.columns == str(value)]
```

If need scalar ouput (if always match):

```
out_scalar = out.iat[0]
```

If need scalar ouput if possible no match:

```
out_scalar  = next(iter(out), 'no match')
```

Comment: The code errors as there is no column named `'4'`. How can we prevent that? @jezrael

Comment: @Vishnudev - Good comment, thank you. Then use `out = df.loc[(df['weekbegin'] == week), df.columns == str(value)]`

Comment: Cool. That addition sums up the answer. @jezrael